# Is there a way to def function with mpi4py?

Tags: python, mpi4py

Have a few modules which need to be called to do certain processes only when it's called.

like:-

```
import os
from mpi4py import MPI
x= ["10","02","03,"04"]
def manta(int):
      os.systems("time manta ripper -l "+x[int]"")
def rip(int):
      os.systems("time rip -b -mb "+x[int]+"")
def save(int):
      os.systems("time merger -h -i "+x[int]" -l -s ")
if rank < 4:
   return(rank)
```

here for each def function it has to run using the rank taken from mpi4py.

Comment: Please post runnable code. Also, using Python builtin types as variable names is a very bad idea. I'm guessing that you want to execute different functions depending on the value of 'rank'. If that is so, then a dictionary keyed on rank with values that equate to the relevant function is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code and also rename the parameter (avoid using built-in Python keywords as names):

```py
import os

x = ["10", "02", "03, "04"]

def manta(index):
      os.systems("time manta ripper -l " + x[index])


def rip(index):
      os.systems("time rip -b -mb " + x[index])


def save(index):
      os.systems("time merger -h -i " + x[index] + " -l -s ")
```

This is a way to run each of the 3 functions sequentially:

```py
# only run if rank can be used as valid index (inside array x)
if rank < 4:
  manta(rank)
  rip(rank)
  save(rank)
else:
  print('Rank outside of range [0..3], given rank was: ' + str(rank))
```

Not sure what the `return` is intended:

```py
if rank < 4:
   return(rank)
```